In VB.net application module getting default value of a textbox in form instead of updated value
In VB.net application module getting default value of a textbox in form instead of updated value.
I have code in Form
 Private Sub FrmLogin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     PanelLogin.Left = (Me.Width / 2) - 150
     PanelLogin.Top = (Me.Height / 2) - 160

     Dim filePath As String = (Application.StartupPath & "\cnd.dll")
     If File.Exists(filePath) Then
         Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
         If lines.Length >= 1 Then TxtServerLocal.Text = lines(0)
         If lines.Length >= 2 Then TxtDbLocal.Text = lines(1)
         If lines.Length >= 3 Then TxtUserLocal.Text = lines(2)
         If lines.Length >= 4 Then TxtPwdLocal.Text = lines(3)
         If lines.Length >= 5 Then TxtPortLocal.Text = lines(4)
     End If
 Private Sub BtnLogin_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
     ErrorProvider1.Clear()

     If TxtUID.Text = "" Then
         ErrorProvider1.SetError(TxtUID, "valid User id required")
         Exit Sub
     End If
     If TxtPD.Text = "" Then
         ErrorProvider1.SetError(TxtPD, "Valid Password required")
         Exit Sub
     End If
     Call Module1.connection()
     Dim command As New MySqlCommand
     Dim strArray As String() = New String() {"Select * from users where userid = @d1 and upd = @d2 and status = '", Conversions.ToString(1), "'"}
     command = New MySqlCommand(String.Concat(strArray), Module1.con)
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Me.TxtUID.Text)
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Me.TxtPD.Text)
     ' command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", Module1.Encrypt(Me.TxtPass.Text))
     MsgBox("," & cs & "")
     Module1.con.Open()
     Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
     If Not reader.HasRows Then
         Interaction.MsgBox("User Id or Password Invalid", MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, Nothing)
         Me.TxtUID.Text = ""
         Me.TxtPD.Text = ""
         ErrorProvider1.SetError(TxtUID, "valid User id required")
         ErrorProvider1.SetError(TxtPD, "Valid Password required")
         Module1.con.Close()
     Else
         reader.Read()
         Me.TxtUID.Text = reader("userid").ToString
         Me.Txtempcode.Text = reader("empcode").ToString
         Me.Txtloginselection.Text = reader("loginselection").ToString
         Me.Txtcompanycode.Text = reader("companycode").ToString
         Module1.con.Close()
         Dim FrmMain As New FrmMain
         ' FrmMain.Show()
         ' Me.Hide()
     End If
End Class

and code in Module1
Module Module1

    Public con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()

    Public cs As String

    Public Sub connection()



        cs = "server=" & FrmLogin.TxtServerLocal.Text & ";database=" & FrmLogin.TxtDbLocal.Text & ";user=" & FrmLogin.TxtUserLocal.Text & ";password=" & FrmLogin.TxtPwdLocal.Text & ";port=" & FrmLogin.TxtPortLocal.Text & ";sslmode=required;"
            'con = ("server=" & FrmLogin.TxtServerLocal.Text & ";database=" & FrmLogin.TxtDbLocal.Text & ";user=" & FrmLogin.TxtUserLocal.Text & ";password=" & FrmLogin.TxtPwdLocal.Text & ";port=" & FrmLogin.TxtPortLocal.Text & ";")
            ' con.Open()
            ' con = New MySqlConnection(cs)
            MsgBox("," & cs & "")
            con = New MySqlConnection(String.Concat(cs))

    End Sub
End Module


Are you talking about the TxtServerLocal field? Is the "default" value the one loaded from the file named "cnd.dll"? (not a good file name, by the way) What's in this field in the Click() handler, right before calling Module1.connection()?

The way you're doing this is bad to begin with. You're calling that connection method from FrmLogin so there's no good reason that that method should then have to retrieve data from that same form. The form should be passing the data in via method parameters. There's a whole lot else that should be changed to but, as you're presumably fairly new to this, one thing at a time.

You should also think a bit harder about the names you use. "connection" is a noun and thus not an appropriate name for a method, which should be verb-based. That con field should be a property named Connection and the connection method should be named CreateConnection or the like, because that's what it actually does. Also, what's the point of assigning a New MySqlConnection to con where you declare it, only to replace that with another New MySqlConnection in the method? Don't create objects you have no intention of using. Also, why are con and cs both Public?

How EXACTLY are you displaying FrmLogin in the first place? Your module is using the default instance to access the TextBox so you would need to have displayed the default instance to the user. If you created your own instance, you're getting the data from a different form object to the one the user entered it into. You should do some research on default instances and learn how to use them and when not to. They are pretty much a hack for beginners and VB6 developers who don't want to learn VB.NET properly.
